# hibernate 4.2 schema based multi-tenancy + c3p0 connection pool

Tags: java, hibernate, multi-tenant

I am running a java app (java 1.7) with hibernate 4.2.0 and I need to implement a schema based multi tenancy setup. I used [this](https://github.com/hibernate/hibernate-orm/blob/master/hibernate-core/src/test/java/org/hibernate/test/multitenancy/schema/SchemaBasedMultiTenancyTest.java) exampleto do that.
my problem is that I was unable to figure out how to create the connection providers. the example uses:

```java
    acmeProvider = ConnectionProviderBuilder.buildConnectionProvider( "acme" );
    jbossProvider = ConnectionProviderBuilder.buildConnectionProvider( "jboss" );
```

but **ConnectionProviderBuilder** is for testing use.

I tried to use the following:

```java
    C3P0ConnectionProvider connectionProvider = new C3P0ConnectionProvider()
    {
        public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease()
        {
            return allowAggressiveRelease;
        }
    };

    connectionProvider.configure(props);
```

the problem here was that the C3P0ConnectionProvider has a null serviceRegistry which crush the with NPE.

does anyone have an idea on how to create ConnectionProvider for each tenant?

Thanks,

Ronen

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26968721/manage-connection-pooling-in-multi-tenant-app-using-hibernate ?

Answer (score 0):

Try [suggestion](https://forum.hibernate.org/viewtopic.php?p=2469076) using `Properties` to add data source properties:

> ```
> DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl cp = new DatasourceConnectionProviderImpl();
> cp.setDataSource(ds);
> Properties p = new Properties();
> // ...
> cp.configure(p);
> ```

Or with [DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl](https://www.tabnine.com/code/java/methods/org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.connections.internal.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl/configure):

> ```
> DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl connectionProvider = new DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl() {
>    public boolean supportsAggressiveRelease() {
>      return allowAggressiveRelease;
>    }
>  };
>  connectionProvider.configure( props );
> ```